# ansible :"unable to set terminal parameters" for cisco devices

Tags: ansible

I am trying to interact with cisco ASA devices ,But keep getting "unable to set terminal parameters" error ,pls help.

```
- hosts: ASA
  #connection: network_cli
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
   cli:
      username: "username"
      password: "password"
      authorize: yes
      auth_pass: "password"
      transport: cli

  tasks:
    - name: run multiple commands and evaluate the output
      asa_command:
         commands:
            - show version
         provider: "{{ cli }}"


TASK [run multiple commands and evaluate the output] 
fatal: [node1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "unable to set terminal parameters"}
fatal: [node2]: FAILED! => {"msg": "unable to set terminal parameters"}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the ASA module but your indentation looks wrong cli is only indented 1 space under vars.

Comment: That's not it, Peter, as one can readily confirm with any standard YAML parser.

Comment: @Raja can you post more verbose output, to see if we can identify who is emitting that message? I see it plenty in the [network plugins](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.6.7/lib/ansible/plugins/terminal/ce.py#L54) but without knowing more specifics it's hard to troubleshoot